# How to set minimum length of 6 in input? [Live seach]

Tags: javascript

How can I display the results with at least two characters? So I'll get faster results list.

I can not use any Submit button, this is auto complete form

HTML :

```
 <input class="form-control btn-group-lg" data-minlength="2" type="text" id="autoCompleteSearch" value="" required="required">
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var data = [
                    "id": "",
                    "soruCore": "",
                    "soruIceri": "",
                    "sik1": ""
                },
            ];
            $('#txt-search').keyup(function () {
                var searchField = $(this).val();
                if (searchField === '') {
                    $('#filter-records').html('');
                    return;
                }
                var regex = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
                var output = '<div class="row" style="margin: 10px;">';
                var count = 1;
                $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                    if ((val.soruIceri.search(regex) != -1) || (val.soruCore.search(regex) != -1)) {
                        output += '<div class="container">';
                        output += '<div class="row">';
                        output += '<h2 style="color: #FFFFFF">' + val.sik1 + '</h2>';
                        output += '</div></div>';
                        output += '</section>';
                        if (count % 2 == 0) {
                            output += '</div><div class="row">';
                        }
                        count++;
                    }
                });
                output += '</div>';
                $('#filter-records').html(output);
            });
        });
```

Comment: Simply drop that `data-minlength` attribute in favour of a proper `minlength` attribute

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
function checkLength(){
var textbox = document.getElementById("textbox");
if(textbox.value.length >= 6)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You should use the [pattern attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-html5-20090825/forms.html#attr-input-pattern). You might need the "required" attribute too because otherwise an empty value will be excluded from constraint validation.

```
<input required pattern=".{6,}" title="6 characters minimum">
<input required pattern=".{6,20}" title="6 to 20 characters">
```

Comment: Too complicated, there's no need for `pattern` when we have `minlength` and `maxlength`